# How to resize an element to full viewable height

Tags: html, css

I'm attempting to make a div that resizes to full page height, between a header and a footer. I don't want there to be any scrolling on the page, I've looked around and can't find a solution that has worked for me.

Here is a picture of my webpage.

[image]

I want the black bordered box to expand all the way down to the drawn red line, no matter the zoom ratio on the browser. Obviously width already works, but I cannot for the life of me get height.

Here is my code:

```
<div class="row" style="height:100%;">
    <div class="col-md-2" style="border:1px solid black;">
        <div class="panel panel-success">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h3 class="panel-title">Links</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                Panel content
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-10" style="border:1px solid black">
        <div class="panel panel-primary">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h3 class="panel-title">Viewer</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                Panel content
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `height: 100%;`

Comment: @CalebAnthony that doesn't work. I tried it in the col-md divs and the row div, and it made no difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set the height on the `html` and `body` to 100%, then you can set the height on the children. I'd advise against setting 100% on the `.row` class since this is Bootstrap, so maybe make your own class. You'd then too need your columns to be 100% height.

```
html, body { height:100% }
.row-wrapper { height:100% }
.row-wrapper .col-md-2, .row-wrapper .col-md-10 {height:100%}    

...

<div class="row row-wrapper">
```

Just keep in mind the css rule `.row-wrapper .col-md-2, .row-wrapper .col-md-10 {height:100%}` isn't very flexible, so I'd recommend creating another class to target both.

Comment: Well, that made my page visibly taller, but it didn't effect my box.

Comment: Saw the problem and I believe a fix has been applied in my update.

Answer (score 2):

Flexbox (not part of Bootstrap 3, unfortunately), or `vh` units are two options.

```
.row-wrapper {height: 100vh;}
```

http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units

Comment: Plus 1 for the link. Wish more people would use it when suggesting flebox.

Answer (score 0):

make position relative for parent div and absolute for child div and it will work for height and width.

Child div get dimensions from parent according to resolution size

```css
#divParent {
  background-color: #0D0201;
  height: 280px;
  position: relative;
}
#divChild {
  background-color: #F20914;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}
@media screen and (min-width: 480px) {
  #divParent {
    height: 380px;
    background-color: #524D4C;
  }
  #divChild {
    background-color: #FF333C;
  }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 680px) {
  #divParent {
    height: 480px;
    background-color: #827F7E;
  }
  #divChild {
    background-color: #F19189;
  }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 980px) {
  #divParent {
    height: 600px;
    background-color: #CFCDCC;
  }
  #divChild {
    background-color: #F7C7C3;
  }
}
```

```html
<body id="divParent">
  <div id="divChild" class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2" style="border:1px solid black;">
      <div class="panel panel-success">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <h3 class="panel-title">Links</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
          Panel content
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-10" style="border:1px solid black">
      <div class="panel panel-primary">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <h3 class="panel-title">Viewer</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
          Panel content
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```